# pipe() and fork() in c

Tags: c, fork, pipe

I need to create two child processes. One child needs to run the command "ls -al" and redirect its output to the input of the next child process, which in turn will run the command "sort -r -n -k 5" on its input data. Finally, the parent process needs to read that (data already sorted) and display it in the terminal. The final result in the terminal (when executing the program) should be the same as if I entered the following command directly in the shell: "ls -al | sort -r -n -k 5". For this I need to use the following methods: pipe(), fork(), execlp().

My program compiles, but I don't get the desired output to the terminal. I don't know what is wrong. Here is the code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int fd[2];
    pid_t ls_pid, sort_pid;
    char buff[1000];

    /* create the pipe */
    if (pipe(fd) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Pipe failed");
        return 1;
    }

    /* create child 2 first */
    sort_pid = fork();
    if (sort_pid < 0) {                         // error creating Child 2 process
        fprintf(stderr, "\nChild 2 Fork failed");
        return 1;
    }
    else if(sort_pid > 0) {                     // parent process

        wait(NULL);                             // wait for children termination

        /* create child 1 */
        ls_pid = fork();
        if (ls_pid < 0) {                       // error creating Child 1 process
            fprintf(stderr, "\nChild 1 Fork failed");
            return 1;
        }
        else if (ls_pid == 0) {                 // child 1 process
            close(1);                           // close stdout
            dup2(fd[1], 1);                     // make stdout same as fd[1]
            close(fd[0]);                       // we don't need this end of pipe
            execlp("bin/ls", "ls", "-al", NULL);// executes ls command
        }

        wait(NULL);
        read(fd[0], buff, 1000);                // parent reads data 
        printf(buff);                           // parent prints data to terminal   
    }
    else if (sort_pid == 0) {                   // child 2 process
        close(0);                               // close stdin
        dup2(fd[0], 0);                         // make stdin same as fd[0]
        close(fd[1]);                           // we don't need this end of pipe
        execlp("bin/sort", "sort", "-r", "-n", "-k", "5", NULL); // executes sort operation
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unless if you are executing from `/`, try replacing "bin/ls" by "/bin/ls" (similar for "/bin/sort" )

Comment: It appears you are doing no error checking.  You should add some, that will help you diagnose the issue.

Comment: I have printf() statements inside the children blocks. Without the "/", it shows me both children statements but when I put the "/" it doesn't show those statements; it is like it doesn't reach the children blocks.

Comment: BTW: execlp() and execvp() perform a PATH search if there is no '/' in the pathname. This can all be read in The Fine Manual. Thay also can return (on error) check the return value and errno IF they return.

Comment: Where did that disease start that prints newlines at the start instead of the end of strings, as in `fprintf(stderr, "\nChild 2 Fork failed");`?

Comment: ok, yes; it looks like it needs the "/" before the "bin/ls". So now I added the "/" and also commented the complete last block that executes the sort in order to check only the ls and I get the right output to the terminal. It shows the same as if I typed "ls -al" directly on the shell. So, the problem must be related to the last block (the sort block).

Comment: @wildplasser, thank you for the "/" note. That is one of the errors I already fixed. Now the problem is that the sort process doesn't run as expected. When I execute the program, it hangs in the sort process, I guess it's waiting for data to sort; so it's like not finding the input of the ls process...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your parent process `wait`s for the sort process to finish before creating the ls process.

The sort process needs to read its input before it can finish. And its input is coming from the ls that won't be started until after the `wait`. Deadlock.

You need to create both processes, then `wait` for both of them.

Also, your file descriptor manipulations aren't quite right. In this pair of calls:

```
close(0);
dup2(fd[0], 0);
```

the close is redundant, since dup2 will automatically close the existing fd 0 if there is one. You should do a `close(fd[0])` after ther dup2, so you only have one file descriptor tied to that end of the pipe. And if you want to be really robust, you should test wither `fd[0]==0` already, and in that case skip the dup2 and close.

Apply all of that to the other dup2 also.

Then there's the issue of the parent process holding the pipe open. I'd say you should close both ends of the pipe in the parent after you've passed them on to the children, but you have that weird `read` from `fd[0]` after the last `wait`... I'm not sure why that's there. If the `ls|sort` pipeline has run correctly, the pipe will be empty afterward, so there will be nothing to read. In any case, you definitely need to close `fd[1]` in the parent, otherwise the sort process won't finish because the pipe won't indicate EOF until all writers are closed.

After the weird `read` is a `printf` that will probably crash, since the read buffer won't be `'\0'`-terminated.

And the point of using `execlp` is that it does the `$PATH` lookup for you so you don't have to specify `/bin/`. My first test run failed because my sort is in `/usr/bin/`. Why hardcode paths when you don't have to?

Comment: thank you so much; I got it working now. I took out the redundant close before the dup2's; I also took out the read() from df[0] after the last wait(). I realized it is not necessary. I added an open(1) statement inside the sort block so that the output of the sort is displayed in the terminal, and I finally took out the buff variable altogether and that last printf since they are not needed.

Comment: Oh!, and I only do the wait(NULL) after both children processes.